# Domain registration

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-domain, deliverability

I am trying to perform a domain registration for a client and it is not giving the expected result. It's a domain they've been using outside of Marketing Cloud for ages and I want to register it for Marketing Cloud now. I've generated the token and sent it to them. When performing a DNS-lookup through mac terminal I can see that the token is on their DNS. However when I try to verify the domain it still says "No matching token was found for this Domain". The token has been on the DNS for about a week now.

The reason I am registering a domain is because they want to use a subdomain to send emails but there is no real "mailbox" behind the subdomain so they can't verify the email address.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I will not recommend to use an entire domain on Marketing Cloud, but rather a subdomain, e.g.: marketing.example.com. Also, I am not sure which "token" you are talking about.

In order to be able to use a subdomain on Marketing Cloud, you should delegate the domain to the name servers of Salesforce:

> You should create NS records for your subdomain, for each of the name
> servers:
>
> 1. ns1.exacttarget.com
> 2. ns2.exacttarget.com
> 3. ns3.exacttarget.com
> 4. ns4.exacttarget.com

as described it in [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subdomain_delegation_guide.htm&type=5).

Once delegated, you should either ask Salesforce to configure the subdomain as a [Sender Authentication Package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_sender_authentication_package.htm&type=5) or a [Private Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318538&language=en_US&type=1) - depending on the use case and the contract.

If you are using the domain/subdomain for other purposes as well, and hence are unable to delegate the entire set of records, you have the option of [self-hosting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_dns_record_maintenance.htm&type=5) it. However this adds some more complexity to the configuration, and also requires Salesforce to provide you with the complete set of DNS settings for you to create.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time. I've followed the steps outlined in this document: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_domain_registration.htm&type=5. What you are explaining sounds a lot different than what I've done so far. I'll look into it :).

Comment: This should also work, depending on the use-case. If you only want to verify the domain, in the most basic way - the TXT record should suffice. However best practice is to go with the private domain/SAP approach.

Comment: Ok that indeed makes sense, thank you! Any idea what the issue might be why Marketing Cloud can't find the matching token?

Comment: It is indeed not possible for me to say without seeing how your DNS has been updated with the token. I will suggest you raise a case with Salesforce Support.

Comment: @LukasLunow if the subdomain doesn't exist yet but company owns domain, what order should the process be? Company purchases subdomain and delegates the DNS records then finally SAP if that's the plan? If company owns domain, Salesforce won't be purchasing correct?